# front door threshold replacement

Tags: door-frame

[image]My front door is a bit sticky. Probably caused  by aging door step, water damage, and foundation repair. What do you recommend?

(1) sand down the existing threshold.  What do I use to seal the old wood?

(2) replace the threshold. How do I do that?

(3) sand down bottom of door?

It is a double door, about 64 inches. There is a wood floor on inside and a wooden board on the exterior side.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your old threshold?

Comment: Possible x-y problem... help us understand why your door sticks in the first place. (Hint: it's usually not the threshold, though it certainly could be.) From the inside, looking at the hinge barrels, is the gap at the hinges wider at the top than it is at the bottom?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Odd. You are right. At bottom left ,it is wide, then on first hinge it becomes tightest, then gradually opens after 2nd and 3rd hinge. At the top it is almost as wide a gap as bottom, but slightly less so. Do I need a vernier to measure?

Comment: Get a couple of 3" screws through the hinge holes into the jamb (and into the framing). Tighten the gap at the top hinge and see how the door works.

Answer (score 1):

If your existing threshold is structurally sound without cracks or water damage, there is no need to replace it.You can sand it down and then coat it with a marine varnish or some other outdoor sealer/stain. 
If your threshold is damaged in any way, then it should be replaced to prevent tripping. The screws that hold the threshold down are usually visible from the top. Remove them and pry up the threshold. Take the removed threshold to you home store and get a replacement close to your original one. You could also take measurements before removing the threshold and do your shopping before removing it. Seal and attach your new threshold following the direction that came with it.